# How to ban someone from my roblox Jailbreak VIP server?

Tags: roblox

I'm the owner of a Jailbreak VIP server on Roblox. I really want to temporarily ban some people: one friend arrested me on Jailbreak, and I want to ban him for a week but I wanna make sure he doesn't join.

I don't want to unfriend him because he's a good friend, So how to ban someone from my jailbreak VIP server?

Comment: you want to ban someone, for arresting you? You do know that's part of the game, right?

Comment: One of my friends just did that though... @hakalo

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I can think of is, remove his name from the join list in the menu for the server and then when he is beeging at your feet to come back, re-enable his access. :D

Answer (score 2):

You don't have admin commands in the game **even if you own the VIP Server**, so there is no basic way of banning someone from the VIP Server. **You can try only making yourself or some other group of people allowed into your VIP Server**, but right now it is not possible to ban someone in your VIP Server.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is go to your VIP server and press or click friends allowed off and change the Vip server link and save.

Answer (score 1):

Disable allow friends, and only allow certain people by putting there username in the allowed section. To do this, click configure private server. It might be a lot of work, but if you really want to do it, you gotta do it.